# how to create a setInterval loop to edit chrome url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

im using a function  to edit the chrome url and wish to create a setInterval loop to keep switching between 2 different urls every 5 seconds.

So i created 2 seperate functions of the different urls, and now im trying to create the setInterval loop but im having trouble with this, how can i do this?

```
function auto_url(){
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
 chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:"www.youtube.com"});
});
}
function auto_url2(){
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
 chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:"www.google.com"});
});
}

 var time = setInterval(setPage, 3000);
 function timer() {
 var arrayOfFunctions = [];
arrayOfFunctions.push(auto_url) = arrayOfFunctions.push(auto_url2) == 
(auto_url) ? auto_url2 : auto_url;
}
for (var key in arrayOfFunctions) {
arrayOfFunctions[key](); // run your function
}
```

I also tried this:

```
function auto_url(){
 chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
 chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:"www.youtube.com"});
 });
 }
 function auto_url2(){
 chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
 chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url:"www.google.com"});
 });
 }
 var webURLS = window["auto_url", "auto_url2"];
 var website = document.querySelector('#web-address');
 function flipper() {
  var timer, count = 0;
  var loop = function loop(count) {
   if (count === webURLS.length) count = 0;
   website.src = webURLS[count];
  timer = setTimeout(loop, 5000, ++count);
 }
  loop(count);
 }
 flipper();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get this done is to use a global variable.

```
var alt = false;

function auto_url() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: "http://www.youtube.com" });
    });
}

function auto_url2() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: "http://www.google.com" });
    });
}

setInterval(function () {
    if (alt) {
        alt = false;
        auto_url();
    } else {
        alt = true;
        auto_url2();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: worked perfectly thanks. Im creating a button in the popup.html to stop the interval loop. Is this code correct? The javascript is in the js file

    <button id='btn' onclick="stop()">Stop Interval</button>

     function stop() {
          clearInterval();
      }

Comment: The button goes in popup.html THEN research how that button links with your background.js code OR you can start and stop by clicking on the extension button itself.